# How to set anchor while resizing page in Corel

Tags: coreldraw

We're using CorelDraw X7 to design our web UI.

Eventually, we need to modify Page Size (Tools > Options > Document > Page Size) and specify the new height as some pages are much longer than others.

However, Corel expands both top and bottom, and all working elements are right in the middle of the page, plus a useless blank space on the very top [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/765kl.png)

We wonder if CorelDraw (X7) has exactly the equivalent function of [Adobe Ps canvas resize with anchor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3ua9.png), which fixes the anchor and expands only other sides.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this Photoshop feature is not available in Corel.

The solution is to make a much bigger page than you need and don't use the pagedimensions.

Then create your own page with a rectangle on a master layer and lock this layer.
You may even use guidelines by dragging the 0-source to the rectangle.
The 'page-rectangle' you CAN expand from the top, see the grid in the upperlefthand when you select the rectangle.

Comment: was this helpful?

Comment: Yes, in the X7 version, I think all we can do is what you said. Thanks for that idea.